# Transaction integrity in asp.net core with entity framework and generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, transactions

I am not very experienced in Entity Framework, I previously used ADO.Net and Dapper for data persistence. For now, I only read Microsoft docs and watched a few video tutorials. I tried to stick to well accepted advice and have built a generic repository infrastructure with the help of from here and there.

#### IEntity

```
public interface IEntity
{
    object Id { get; set; }

    string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity<T> : IEntity
{
    new T Id { get; set; }
}
```

#### BaseEntity

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> : IEntity<T>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public T Id { get; set; }

    object IEntity.Id { get { return Id; } set { } }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    private DateTime? createdOn;
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get { return createdOn ?? DateTime.UtcNow; }
        set { createdOn = value; }
    }

    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

#### User Entity

```
public class User : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

#### IRepository

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity: IEntity
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
                      string includeProperties = null,
                      int? skip = null,
                      int? take = null);

    TEntity GetFirst(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
                     Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
                     string includeProperties = null);

    TEntity GetById(object id);

    TEntity GetOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
                   string includeProperties = null);

    void Create(TEntity entity, string createdBy = null);

    void Update(TEntity entity, string modifiedBy = null);

    void Delete(TEntity entity);

    void Delete(object id);

    void Save();
}
```

#### EFRepository

```
public class EFRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    private DbContext _context;

    public EFRepository(BlogContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetQueryable(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = null,
    int? skip = null,
    int? take = null)
    {
        includeProperties = includeProperties ?? string.Empty;
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = _context.Set<TEntity>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        if (skip.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
        }

        if (take.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Take(take.Value);
        }

        return query.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null, int? skip = null, int? take = null)
    {
        return GetQueryable(orderBy: orderBy, includeProperties: includeProperties, skip: skip, take: take);
    }

    public TEntity GetById(object id)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public TEntity GetFirst(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null)
    {
        return GetQueryable(filter: filter, orderBy: orderBy, includeProperties: includeProperties).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public TEntity GetOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, string includeProperties = null)
    {
        return GetQueryable(filter: filter, includeProperties: includeProperties).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    public void Create(TEntity entity, string createdBy = null)
    {
        entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        entity.CreatedBy = createdBy;
        _context.Add<TEntity>(entity);
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity, string modifiedBy = null)
    {
        entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        entity.CreatedBy = modifiedBy;
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        var dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();

        if (_context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            dbSet.Attach(entity);

        dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entity = _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        Delete(entity);
    }
}
```

#### IService

```
public interface IService
{
    IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>(DbContext context) where T : class, IEntity;
}
```

#### BaseService

```
public abstract class BaseService : IService
{
    public BaseService(BlogContext context, ILogger<BaseService> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected DbContext _context { get; set; }

    protected readonly ILogger<BaseService> _logger;

    public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>(DbContext context) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return new EFRepository<T>((BlogContext)context);
    }
    public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return GetRepository<T>(_context);
    }
}
```

#### IUserService

```
public interface IAuthorService
{
    bool DeleteAuthorWithEntireStuff(int userId);
}
```

#### UserService

```
public class UserService : BaseService, IAuthorService
{
    public UserService(BlogContext context, ILogger<UserService> logger) : base(context, logger) { }

    public bool DeleteAuthorWithEntireStuff(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var userRepo = GetRepository<User>();
            var commentRepo = GetRepository<Comment>();
            var postRepo = GetRepository<Post>();

            var user = userRepo.GetAll().Where(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null)
            {
                var commentList = commentRepo.GetAll().Where(c => c.UserId == id).ToList();
                var postList = postRepo.GetAll().Where(p => p.AuthorId == id).ToList();

                foreach (var item in commentList)
                    commentRepo.Delete(item);

                foreach (var item in postList)
                    postRepo.Delete(item);

                userRepo.Delete(user);

                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

#### And finally controller

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<User> _repository;
    private readonly IUserService _authorService;

    public UserController(IRepository<User> repository, IUserService authorService)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _authorService = authorService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]User model)
    {
        try
        {
            _repository.Create(model);
            _repository.Save();
            return Ok(model);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }

    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DeletUserEntirely")]
    public IActionResult DeleteUserEntirely([FromBody]User model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_authorService.DeleteUserEntirely(model.Id))
                return Ok();
            else
                return BadRequest();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }

    }
}
```

As you see in the UserService code when I need to run multiple commands in one transaction, I make use of the [ef's unit of work](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core#using-a-custom-repository-versus-using-ef-dbcontext-directly) (`_context.SaveChanges()`).

I did not create any extra unit of work classes as suggested at [few places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429628/2289430) or wrap my repos in transaction scope. As discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/issues/46), some people defend unit of work implementations for transaction integrity that I do not still get it why while ef implementing uow pattern already.

I haven't tested above code so much but till now it seems ok.

Btw, I used [Chris Pratt's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62690/chris-pratt) [Generic Repository](https://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/) approach.
Any problems with this approach, especially with the perspective of transactions  in generic repository use entity framework?

Comment: The repository-pattern is like a virus. It's spreading everywhere and causes only harm ;-)

Comment: You should really avoid the repository approach, and instead look at something like https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/ .

Comment: "I tried to stick to well accepted advice and have built a generic repository" . To me that's a *contradictio in terminis*.